# PHP: How to provide non-primitive default values for properties in traits?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, traits

Is there any way to provide default objects for properties in traits?

```
trait myTrait{
  private $foo = 0; // works
  private $bar = new stdClass(); // doesn't work.
}
```

I know it might seems as a bad coding style to instantiate an concrete object as default value (due to high coupling). The idea here is to provide a [NullObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for an optional depency.

### Example use-case

A better example (the one I'm currently thinking about):

Use a Trait for Logging and implement the default `NullLogger` of the [PSR-3 Logging](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md) as default attribute:

```
trait LoggerTrait{
  /**
    * @var Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
    */
  protected $logger;

  public function setLogger(Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger){
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }
}

class Foo{
  use LoggerTrait;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->setLogger(new Psr\Log\NullLogger()); // I would like to avoid this line as I'd need to duplicate it in every class I'm using the LoggerTrait.
  }

  public function doStuff(){
    $this->logger->info("Yey flexible logging with no overhead!");
  }

}
```

This works, but I have to set the `NullLogger` explicitly in every class that uses the trait and I would like to avoid this "duplication of code".

*PS: I'm sure some one will bring up that the logger could also be inserted via DI-container. That is true but imho not really necessary. See this [blog post + comments](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2014/03/17/avoiding-optional-dependencies/) for some pro/contra arguments :)*

Comment: IIRC you can't do this even with regular properties.  Traits effectively become part of the classes they are used on, kind of like a pre-compiler process.

Answer (score 1):

A common way of solving this problem is using a `getter` within the class, even though the class owns the property.

```
trait LoggerTrait{
    /**
     * @var Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    public function setLogger(Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger){
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function getLogger()
    {
        if(null === $this->logger) {
            $this->logger = new Psr\Log\NullLogger();
        }

        return $this->logger;
    }
}
```

This way the default object isn't even instantiated until it is needed.

```
class Foo{
    use LoggerTrait;

    public function doStuff(){
        $this->getLogger()->info("Yey flexible logging with no overhead!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a suitable approach, altough I don't really like the `$this->getLogger()->info(...)` notation :). +1'd but I'll leave open for some more time.